# How can i dynamically make webpages outputs it's title and metas based on url

Tags: php

I have this website am designing, am using the `include()` function in php to echo texts and other pages. the thing here is that, i just want one header file and one footer file, the footer file i've gotten that worked out but i want the header file to be able to show it's title, meta keywords and meta description (if view source) based on the page the user wants to visit. For Example

URL 1: index.php will have this as it's title

```
<title>This is the Home page</title>
<meta name="keyword" content="this, home, page" />
<meta name="description" content="welcome to home page" />
```

URL 2: about.php will have this as it's title

```
<title>About us</title>
<meta name="keyword" content="about, us, page" />
<meta name="description" content="This website is about" />
```

I hope am conveying this questions correctly. so the thing now is that if the user goes to a different page say `contact.php` the title should dynamically change the text i've written about the contact us page and metas should as well change to what i've written it to be. so can anyone help with this issue because am thinking using php arrays but i don't know how to structure the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be dynamic, i suggest you use a function instead. You call the function instead of using include. eg

```
function printHeader($title, $name, $content) {
    echo "<title>{$title}</title>
          <meta name='{$name[0]}' content='{$content[0]}' />
          <meta name='{$name[1]}' content='{$content[1]}' />";
}
```

You call the function instead of using include().

Comment: the thing here is that, i have the entire website written in a config.php file, so i used the include() function to include other pages and the print statement to output text and other script that works on the site. so if a user clicks on another page the title tag as well as the metas for that particular page dynamically changes to suite it's content. I tried using php array whereby i use the array_map() function but the thing here it gives me the url of one particular page on all the pages. hope you get my point.

Comment: Not so sure I get your question well. But it seems your design patern makes it hard to build dynamic pages, consider changing it & using functions & classes.

Answer (score -1):

Just declare a variable with the information **before** you call the include.  For example:

```
<?php
$title="Your title here";
include("header.inc.php");
...
```

Then, in the header file:
    <title><?php echo $title;?></title>